# Get anything after first slash in URL

Tags: c#, url, slash

I can get my browser url using : `string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`
But say if I have a url as below :

```
http://www.test.com/MyDirectory/AnotherDir/testpage.aspx
```

How would I get the "MyDirectory" part of it, is there a utility in .NET to get this or do I need string manipulation ?

If I do string manipulation and say anything after first instance of "/" then wouldnt it return the slash after http:? It would work if my url was `www.test.com/MyDirectory/AnotherDir/testpage.aspx`

Can someone please help

Comment: Did you check other properties of the class, e.g. [`AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instantiate a Uri instance from your url:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.test.com/MyDirectory/AnotherDir/testpage.aspx");
```

You can then get the path segments into a string array using:

```
string[] segments = myUri.Segments
```

Your first "MyDirectory" folder will be at:

```
string myFolderName = segments[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get this by `PathAndQuery` property of `Url`

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
```

it will return `/MyDirectory/AnotherDir/testpage.aspx`

Answer (score 2):

```
 Uri uriAddr = new Uri("http://www.test.com/MyDirectory/AnotherDir/testpage.aspx");
 var firstSegment= uriAddress.Segments.Where(seg => seg != "/").First();
```